# How to add foreign key "with more than one column" in SQL Power Architect

Tags: database-diagrams

In the following picture, I have a model that I'm building in SQL Power Architect:

[image]

I already have table *1* referencing a column (`CDCONTR`) from table *2*. But I want to make the foreign key to reference two columns from table *2*, I mean, both the column `CDCONTR` and `CPF` must come from table *2*. How can I do this?

I'm using SQL Power Architect 1.0.7. About my RDBMS, I'm just using this power arch.

Comment: You can only reference the PK from a foreign key. The PK of `TABCONTRATOA` consists **only** of `CDCONTR` so that's the only column you can reference. If you think you need to reference both, you need to include `CPF` in the primary key of `TABCONTRATOA`

Answer (score 0):

If the `CPF` value in `TABASSASSINATES` should always be the value from the related `CONTRATOA` table, it is redundant data.  Foreign keys won't enforce the relationship.

In other cases, the column will have applicable business rules, and you may not want to force the value in `TABASSINATES` to change when the `CONTERATOA` value is updated. The business rules won't appear in the model you have extracted above.

If it is possible to have multiple `CPF` values in `CONTERATOA` for the same `CDCONTR` value, the *primary key* should include `CPF`.  In this case, the *foreign key* relationship will include both columns.

It is possible, but highly discouraged, to model the `CONTERTOA` *primary key* with both columns and add a *unique contraint* on the `CDCONTR` column.